# Disabling space as first character in input field doesnt work on Chrome Android/App

Tags: javascript

I have this code that basically disables adding in an empty space inside an input field, however it doesn't seem to run on Chrome Mobile/App/Android.

Does anyone have any solutions?

```
<script>
document.getElementById('firstname').addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
  if (this.value.length === 0 && evt.which === 32) evt.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which (non-standard, do not use in production, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `KeyboardEvent.code` instead

```js
document.getElementById('firstname').addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
  if (this.value.length === 0 && evt.code === 'Space') 
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input id="firstname">
```

Comment: Much like my code, I can't get it to run on Chrome Android. It works fine on Desktop and on Safari, but doesnt on mobile.

Comment: have you tried to debug the script with an alert? does the key down listener fire when you press the spacebar? I tried it in safari on an iPhone and it's working.

Comment: It works on Safari, Chrome Desktop and Firefox. But on Chrome Mobile it seems not to function. I tried all sorts of versions and I think it might just be the way Chrome Mobile version currently is.

Comment: Chrome on iPhone is also working... is the keydown event firing on your Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent, `KeyboardEvent.which` is deprecated. Use `KeyboardEvent.key` instead.

Also see [list of key codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).

```js
document.getElementById('firstname').addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
  if (this.value.length === 0 && evt.key === " ") evt.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input id="firstname">
```

Comment: This works fine. But on Chrome Mobile/Android it doesn't work, the user can add in empty spaces in the input field for some reason. On Desktop it works fine, on Safari it works fine.